# How to fix "Not allowed to load local resource" error in electron because of "#" converted into "%23"

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron

I'm creating an angular-electron app (Angular 7). I want to load a new BrowserWindow, but I'm getting "Not allowed to load local resource".

It's everything okay if I'm trying to load just index.html. But the problem is when I want to load '/index.html#/settings'.

```
// Create a browser window
var win = new BrowserWindow({
       width: 800,
       height: 600,
       center: true,
       resizable: false,
       frame: true,
       transparent: false
     });
// Load the page + route
win.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html#/settings');
```

I can see in error message that '#' in URL is converted into '%23', so instead '.../index.html#/settings' it tries to load '.../index.html%23/settings'. I assume if I could prevent converting '#' into '%23' I wouldn't have this problem.

**Full error:**

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///Users/username/Development/trackapp/release/mac/The%20Track%20Tim…ces/app.asar/dist/index.html%23/settings

Comment: What about directly redirecting from your angular app instead?

Comment: @briosheje  I assumed it would be easier to just add like it is (Not an angular pro really). Btw, I'm checking if it's production or dev, and if it's dev I run win.loadURL('http://localhost:4200/#/settings/') and everything works fine. But the bug described is on packaged electron app.

Comment: that's because of security policies, due to the browser instance trying to load an insecure resource. Does it work properly with `win.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');`?

Comment: @briosheje Yes, _"It's everything okay if I'm trying to load just index.html. But the problem is when I want to load '/index.html#/settings'."_

Comment: @briosheje Also, I'm confident it would work if '#' isn't replaced with "%23". I get the same error message when file isn't found. If I could prevent electron(or angular) from converting '#' to '%23' it will probably work fine.

Comment: @briosheje I updated the question. Added full error message.

Comment: I've never experienced such issue with angular and electron. Perhaps you may think about changing the routing strategy: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/routing-strategies/ .